# How to put {,},(,) in enum

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to group bunch of bracts in java `enum`. Can some one tell me how to do this? I tried following

```
enum sample{'{','}';}
enum sample{"{","}";}
enum sample{{,};}
```

none of them compiles.

Comment: You mean enum? You misspelled it 4 times....

Comment: Sorry I just corrected them all, Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that `enum` can have a custom constructor:

```
public enum Bracket {
  OPEN_BRACKET('{'), CLOSE_BRACKET('}');

  private final char symbol;

  Brackets(char symbol) {
      this.symbol = symbol;
  }

  public char getSymbol() {
      return symbol;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! This is the first time I saw construct enum like this

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an enum with custom toString() methods that will return your custom strings:

```
public enum MyType {
ONE {
    public String toString() {
        return "{";
    }
},

TWO {
    public String toString() {
        return "}";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`enum` doesn't allow special characters. It only allows alphanumeric with first letter a char.
So u can't have {,},etc.. It follows the same naming convention as variables.